# Максимальная длина последовательности – 254. Первый байт должен содержать информацию о фактическом количестве элементов массива

Tags: c++, ооп

Есть задачка

> Создать класс для работы со строчками. Максимальная длина последовательности – 254. Первый байт должен содержать информацию о фактическом количестве элементов массива. Совершить перегрузку операций

Как именно должно выглядеть вот эта часть условия?

> Максимальная длина последовательности – 254.Первый байт должен содержать информацию о фактическом количестве элементов массива

Comment: Что конкретно Вам неясно в данной задаче? Если вспомнить о том, как работают типы данных в C++, то arr[0] = (char) *фактический размер массива в целочисленном представлении*. А если вы хотите получить размер массива, то следует сделать size = (int) arr[0]

Comment: @NkL322, только не (int)arr[0], а `((unsigned char *)arr)[0]`, иначе для размера строки больше 127 size будет отрицательным (или если size unsigned, то очень большим)